# Javascript hasher nested function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I am trying to create a function that will trim off array values that are not 4 chars long. For some reason, it does not work. I think that it might be with the return statement but I am not sure and I need help with it. Here is the code for the function: (Please don't suggest ways of making the hasher better, I just need help on the function)

```
function cutit(seq){
        for(var i=0;i<seq.length;i++){
            var temparr=seq[i].split("");
            if(temparr.length % 4 !== 0){
                seq.splice(seq[i],1);
                return seq;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Five things:

- Yes, the `return` should happen *after* the loop not after the first found item to delete.
- `.splice()` takes an index for the first parameter, not the element. Pass `i` instead of `seq[i]`.
- `splice(…, 1)` does decrease the length of the array you're iterating over by one. You need to take care of that and decrease your counter as well to have a look at the `i` index again, where on the next iteration the next element will sit.
- Instead of splitting the string into an array of single chars and taking the length of that, just take the length of the string directly.
- Your functions removes all strings that are not a *multiple of* 4 long, not all that are not exactly 4 characters long. Not sure whether that is intended.

```
function cutit(seq) {
    for (var i=0; i<seq.length; i++) {
        if (seq[i].length !== 4) {
            seq.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }
    return seq;
}
```

Also, notice that mutating an array is seldom a good idea (especially in an inefficient way like this with multiple splices). Returning a new array is so much easier, and you can use the higher-order [`filter` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that:

```
function cutit(seq) {
    return seq.filter(function(str) {
        return str.length === 4;
    });
}
```